# Socket.io setup causes hundreds of transport polling GET requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I'm using express.js server-side and I followed the socket.io [setup guide](http://socket.io/docs/). Unfortunately the socket connection is never successful, and I receive an unruly amount of GET requests that look like this:

[image]

Here's my setup:

**CLIENT - index.html**

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.7.js"></script>
 <script>
  // var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:9000/');

  socket.on('connected', function (serverData) {
    console.log(serverData);
  });
</script>
```

**SERVER - /io/index.js**

```
'use strict';
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var io = null;

module.exports = function(server) {

    if (io) return io;

    io = socketio(server);

    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        console.log('Sockets connected!');
        socket.emit('connected', 'Sockets connected!')
    })

    return io;

};
```

**SERVER - app.js**

```
'use strict';

// Set default node environment to development
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('./config/environment');

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect(config.mongo.uri, config.mongo.options);
mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error('MongoDB connection error: ' + err);
  process.exit(-1);
});

// Populate databases with sample data
if (config.seedDB) { require('./config/seed'); }

// Setup server
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
require('./config/express')(app);
require('./routes')(app);

// Setup sockets
require('./io')(server);

// Start server
function startServer() {
  server.listen(config.port, config.ip, function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on %d, in %s mode', config.port, app.get('env'));
  });
}

setImmediate(startServer);

// Expose app
exports = module.exports = {
    app: app,
    server: server
}
```

Comment: Note: requiring socket.io on the client side via `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` as directed by the docs results in a [successful server connection but an unexpected token error in the client console](http://imgur.com/a/Po5BZ).

Comment: maybe tell server-side you are listening on port 9000 ! client try on server port 9000 `var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:9000/');`

Comment: Thanks @Anonymous0day, but I'm doing exactly that on the clientside and the server is indeed listening on 9000. If I hard code 9000 to the server I still get the same error (100s of polling requests)

Comment: and what about : `require('./io')(server);`, if you change to :`require('./io/index.js')(server);`

Comment: thanks for the follow up but that doesn't work either :( @Anonymous0day

Answer (score 0):

This is tipically what happen, when client does not reach the server.
The client try again and again . . .
For that you have to check your config server-side, checking the port and the path is often the first things you should check.

In your case, maybe you should check this part :

```
//require('./io')(server);  typo error ??       
require('./io/index.js')(server);
```

More further you don't seem to give the good part :
*( maybe depending on version you use)*

```js
// Setup server
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
require('./config/express')(app);
require('./routes')(app);

// Setup sockets
require('./io')(server);
```

I think it should be :

```
// Setup server
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
require('./config/express')(app);
require('./routes')(app);

// Setup sockets
//require('./io')(server); |O----------------------------------|
require('./io/index.js')(app);//<---we pass app as argument----|
```

I hope this will help you.